# I want to change the type of DB table field from number to text type I should use

Tags: sql

I want to change the type of db table from number to text type I should use _ operator

Comment: OK.Thank you for keeping us informed

Comment: Please read text of the `sql` tag. It says to *also* tag your question with the RDBMS that you're using.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

declare @a as int = 25

select cast (@a as nvarchar (255)) as example

for more details, you can read this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(CONVERT_TSQL);k(sql13.swb.tsqlresults.f1);k(sql13.swb.tsqlquery.f1);k(MiscellaneousFilesProject);k(DevLang-TSQL)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I think the question is about changing the type of the column in the table, not just converting it when selecting. You could put a comment on the question to see whether they do mean they want to change the type of the column